# Transponate / denormalize rows in talend

Tags: talend

I have the following data (values are just examples)

```
ID | VALUE | TYPE
---+-------+-----
 1 | val1A | colA
 1 | val1B | colB
 2 | val2A | colA
 2 | val2B | colB
```

And I want to transponate / denormalize it so it looks like this:

```
ID |  colA |  colB
---+-------+------
 1 | val1A | val1B
 2 | val2A | val2B
```

I tried using the tDenomarlize component but as I already thought it doesn't give the correct format (it just puts all the values in one column)

Any other Ideas? I thought of using tAggregate but I can't think of how to get the values based on type then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tPivotToColumnsDelimited component.
Connect your input data component to tPivotToColumnsDelimited

In Basic setting :
select pivot column as TYPE, Aggregation column as VALUE, Aggregation function as last and Group by as ID

last select the file name into which you want to load the data.

Hope this help..

Comment: yeah, thanks! It does exactly what I need.

At least for small amounts of data.. I currently run out of memory, but I guess I'll find a solution for that